# Google reCaptcha when you don't control the POST URL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, recaptcha

I have a form that submits to a POST action URL I don't have control over, which leaves server-side validation on that URL out of the question.  I need to be able to pass a pen test with reCaptcha and am curious if the below scenario would work.

One idea I had was to do all the normal client-side reCaptcha validation using the callback response and then enabling the submit button via JS.

That button would preventDefault() to submit the form to a different PHP file (via ajax).  That PHP file would perform proper server-side validation, then based on the response submit the form to the main post url on the success ajax response or not via the error response via JS.

I could also load the form without a POST URL then populate the URL in the DOM based on the success ajax response prior to JS submit.

Does anyone have any better ideas or other ways I can validate recaptcha server-side even if I don't have control over the main POST URL?

Or do you think that client-side only validation could pass a pen test?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Do you have a server running PHP that you do have control of? If so, you could post to your own server, do the reCaptcha validation and then forward the POST data onto the third party URL

Comment: The server hosting the site is PHP and I do have access to its back-end.  You make a great point that I could then pass all the form values to the POST URL I don't have control over from my back-end after server-side validation occurs and not have to come back to the client-side and then back out to the other post server.  Great idea @spectacularbob